# custom compare method in objective c

Tags: objective-c, methods, compare

I'm trying to use a custom compare method (for use with `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`) and on another website I got that the format is:

```
-(NSComparisonResult) orderByName:(id)otherobject {
```

That's all very well and good, except how do I compare the `otherObject` to anything as there's only one thing passed to the method?

Like how does the `NSString` method of `compare:` compare 2 strings when only one string is passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison is always between `otherObject` and `self`.

Comment: To clarify: `[someString compare:@"bar"]` would compare `someString` to the string liertal `@"bar"`.  The object you are missing is the object you call the compare method on.  So, within the method `self` is compared to `otherObject`.